# Possible to have a document always return above certain position

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I've got a bunch of documents from a query which are sorted by a modified date. However I'd like certain documents (identified by a field value) to *always* return in the top ten results regardless of whether there are ten or more documents with a more recent modified date.

From what I've read about the various ways of sorting in Elasticsearch (score, boost, scripts) I don't think I have any way of determining the actual position of a document in the search results, let alone some way of manipulating the score to push a document into the top ten.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a field called "important_field" which contains value 1, for documents you in top and say 0 for all other documents, you can use multi field sorting as below

```
{
    "sort": [
        { "important_field": { "order": "desc" }},
        { "modified_date": { "order": "desc" }}
    ]
}
```

This way of sorting means it will sort by important_field value and if they are same then will be sorted by modified_date. So all documents with important_field value 1 will come on top and rest will still be sorted by modified_date.